# Android broadcast receiver (screen) not working on Moto g

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, motorola-droid

I am trying to capture screen on/off event on moto g phone. Main activity has

```
Intent intentscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenService.class);
startService(intentscreen);
```

where as "ScreenService" looks like:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent!=null)
        {

            super.onCreate();
            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , "MyWifiLock");
            if(!wifiLock.isHeld()){
                               wifiLock.acquire();
            }
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
            registerReceiver(this.mybroadcast, filter);
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        } 
        return START_STICKY;
}
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
        if(wifiLock.isHeld()){
                  wifiLock.release();
         }
    }
```

while the receiver class looks like:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.d("Screen", "--- I Fire!");

       }
    }
```

Manifest file has the permission, but the issue is that my phone receives the event for first few hours and then it stops receiving i.e. `Log.d("Screen", "--- I Fire!");` is not displayed in my log cat.

Also to add further, if I acquire `PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock` it doesn't work at all, but if I acquire `WifiLock wifiLock = null`, this works for few hours, any suggestion that how to keep the Wifi active probably?

Any suggestion that what possibly be wrong? Or any other type of lock should I acquire? I dont want to use a lot of battery for locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service gets killed by the system due to low memory it will later be restarted with null passed as the intent. When this happens it appears you would lose broadcast receiver as you do nothing if intent is null.

Seems like it's not possible to get these broadcasts from a static receiver in the android manifest. So you'll probably have to keep your service.

Something along these lines:

```
public void onCreate (){
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the point clearly, can you give an example that what should i do? I thought return sticky will keep the intent not null finally.

Comment: Remove your null check on intent, move your receiver init code to onCreate (also remove explicit call to onCreate) and remove your wake lock.

Comment: Even if you have a sticky service the system can still kill it, it will just restart it again after it's been killed. When that happens you get null as the intent. Also, you never actually start it as sticky as you return whatever super returns instead of the sticky when intent is not null.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let me try this..I will get back with the results.

Comment: Thanks, its working now, just a quick question my app is working on Samsung g 3 and nexus 4, but on Moto g neither it crashes nor it sense at regular/defined time interval, can you comment on that? I mean the app senses from multiple sensors but the time delay is not as i defined using ScheduledExecutorService, it too sparse. Is this because of hardware? or memory? Your suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: And just to be clear, that previously in my solution, the oncreate gets called by default, if the intent is null? Still i have some missing connection, though its working.

Comment: In your previous code you manually called onCreare from onStartCommand, you shouldn't do that as onCreare will be called by the system. Your null check in your old code meant that you skipped all the code if the intent was null

Comment: Not sure I understand what the issue is with the Moro g, is it that the broadcast takes a long time after you turn on the screen? As a rule. Broadcasts may take a very long time to be delivered up to 20 seconds or so depending on system load. Regarding the ScheduledExecturoService, if your device goes to sleep you may have better success with an alarm http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: Thank you very much, i did moved to alarm manager now and sensing on phone is smooth now.